# How to correctly write my relationship/associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 Models and i am not sure what is the correct way to write my relationships/associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boards
  has_many :lists
  has_many :cards
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :lists
end


class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :cards
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list
end
```

Comment: this looks fine to me. can you go into more detail about how you need them to behave or what is not currently working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be more explicit about your relationships, feel free to do the following (preferred in most every case):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boards, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, inverse_of: user, dependent: :destroy
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :boards
 has_many :lists, inverse_of: :board
end


class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :lists
  belongs_to :board, inverse_of :lists
  has_many :cards, inverse_of :list
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :cards
  belongs_to :list, inverse_of :cards
end
```

Finally, make sure any of your models that are dependent on another (e.g. `Board` *belongs_to* `User`) have the appropriate foreign key in their table. So, for example, `Board` will need to have a `user_id` foreign key to correctly create the association.

You can create a migration for any of those entities if you haven't already like so:

`rails generate migration AddUserRefToBoards user:references`